# Linux device driver not behaving as expected

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a simple device driver. The driver has only read/write operations. Ideally, I would like the read() function to work in such a way that when the device file is read from, a message is printed to terminal along with a count of how many times the device file was read from. The driver contains the following libraries and global variables:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/irq.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <linux/poll.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include "my_driver.h"

#define DEVICE_NAME "Edev"
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE -1
#define BUF_LEN 1024

static struct class * cls;

static int major_num;
static int counter=0;
static char message_buffer[BUF_LEN];
static char * message_pointer;
static char * write_pointer;

static struct file_operations elliott_fops = {
    .read=device_read,
    .write=device_write,
    .owner=THIS_MODULE
};
```

The read function is written like so:

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file * filp2, char *buffer2, size_t length2, loff_t *offset2){
    ssize_t bytes_in_message=0;
    sprintf(message_buffer,"Yes,you read from the driver this many times: %d",counter++);
    message_pointer=message_buffer;
    while (length2 && *message_pointer++){
        put_user(*(message_pointer++),buffer2++);
        bytes_in_message++;
        length2--;
    }
    pr_info("Read %lu bytes with %lu bytes remaining in the buffer",bytes_in_message,length2);
    return bytes_in_message;
}
```

What I would like the read() function to do is print the message out to the terminal using the sprint() call, and then the while loop will obtain the message's byte length. The message byte length information as well as the remaining buffer size will then be logged within the kernel

The write function is written like this:

```
static ssize_t device_write(struct file * filp, const char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset){
    ssize_t bytes_read_in=0;
    while (length && *buffer++){
        get_user(*(write_pointer++),buffer++);
        bytes_read_in++;
    }
    pr_info("The device had %lu bytes written to it",bytes_read_in);
    pr_info("Got message from user: %s",write_pointer);
    return bytes_read_in;
}
```

Ideally, if someone performed a write to the device with a "echo "hello linux kernel" > /dev/Edev" command, the message that was written to the device file would be printed in the kernel, as well as how long the message was. However, the read() and write() functions are not behaving like this at all. If, for instance, I load the module and write to the device file, no message have been logged in the kernel. If I then performed a cat /dev/Edev command, what is printed to terminal output is not the message with the count, but rather what was just written to the device with echo.

I am assuming this may have something to do with buffers overwriting each other, but I am confused as the buffer in write is userspace, while the buffer in read is in kernel space. I also am unsure why no messages are being logged to the kernel.

Comment: It looks like `device_write` is relying on userspace to have null-terminated the data it's writing.  That's not a safe assumption and in particular `echo` doesn't do so.  Moreover your `*buffer++` reads from userspace without going through `get_user` which is also unsafe.

Comment: You also seem to have no protection against a long write overrunning your buffer.  I know it's just test code being written as an exercise, but all the same it's horrifying - a buffer overflow in the kernel is one of the worst vulnerabilities you can imagine.

Comment: Oh, and `device_write` increments `buffer` twice on each iteration, which is wrong.  Same for `message_pointer` in `device_read`.

Comment: What is `write_pointer` pointing to in the first place?

Comment: And `length` is not decremented in the loop in `device_write`, so that part of the test will always stay true.

Comment: And you don't check the return values of `get_user` or `put_user`.  Basically, this might be a situation where you need to come back in a couple of hours and read what you actually wrote, instead of what you thought you were writing.  As it stands your density of bugs per LOC is awfully high, and it's hard to figure out just which one of them is responsible for the misbehavior you observe.

Comment: The `put_user()` and `get_user()` macros evaluate their arguments more than once, so the post-increment `++` operators will screw it up. You also have additional post-increment `++` operators in the loop that will screw it up even more.

Comment: Actually, I think `put_user()` and `get_user()` do only evaluate their arguments once, so ignore most of my previous comment, but you are still incrementing variables more than once in the loop.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, I can see why that would be catastrophic possibly. Would the best way to get around this add a null terminating character to the end of the buffer in device_write() and to use copy_from_user() instead which has a third parameter which dictates how much data is read from userspace?

Answer (score 1):

to copy a block of data into userspace for ref ([https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/teaching/lectures/opsys/13_14/docs/kernelAPI/r4037.html](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eexr/teaching/lectures/opsys/13_14/docs/kernelAPI/r4037.html))
use `copy_to_user` function.

Answer (score 1):

There is too much use of the post-increment operator in the loop in `device_read()`:

```
    while (length2 && *message_pointer++){
        put_user(*(message_pointer++),buffer2++);
        bytes_in_message++;
        length2--;
    }
```

`message_pointer` has been incremented twice per iteration.  Similarly, in `device_write()`:

```
    while (length && *buffer++){
        get_user(*(write_pointer++),buffer++);
        bytes_read_in++;
    }
```

`buffer` has been incremented twice per iteration.  Also the `length` variable is not being decremented and the `write_pointer` variable has not been set.

The modified loops can be as follows.  In `device_read()`:

```
    while (length2 && *message_pointer){
        put_user(*message_pointer, buffer2);
        message_pointer++;
        buffer2++;
        bytes_in_message++;
        length2--;
    }
```

And in `device_write()`:

```
    while (length && *buffer){
        get_user(*write_pointer,buffer);
        write_pointer++;
        buffer++;
        bytes_read_in++;
        length--;
    }
```

The `write_pointer` variable still needs to be set to point to a valid buffer in `device_write()`.

[EDIT: Removed paragraph about `put_user()` and `get_user()` evaluating their arguments more than once, as I do not think that is the case.]